# Can I dictate that a C# type parameter must only be an interface type?

Tags: c#, generics, type-constraints

I would like to implement a generic C# class which looks roughly as follows:

```
abstract class Foobar<T> : AbstractBase, T
{ ... }
```

This fails because C# will only allow types after the base class to be interfaces, so next I try this:

```
abstract class Foobar<T> : AbstractBase, T where T : interface
{ ... }
```

But then I find that C# does not allow this form of type constraint.  Only `where T : struct` and `where T : class` are allowed.

How can I dictate that a type parameter must only be an interface type?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? I can't really think of a situation where such a constraint would be necessary.

Answer (score 6):

Basically, you can't.

You can make a contstraint to a specific interface, but not a general one for all interfaces. So you can constrain to IEnumerable for example, but not *any* interface.

What do you need this for anyway?

Comment: I noticed that all classes deriving from Foobar<T> also end up implementing T.  I thought I could perhaps enforce this being the case by moving the `implements Blah` from my derived classes up onto the base class Foobar.

Answer (score 5):

The real problem with that code is that you are inheriting from a type parameter.

Trying to compile

```
abstract class Foobar<T> : T { ... }
```

will still fail with:  error CS0689: Cannot derive from 'T' because it is a type parameter.

I think that this would be perfectly reasonable at least in the case of abstract classes, and I wanted this feature too, but the c# compiler just wont let you do that.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the core of the problem (deriving from type parameters).

Answer (score 1):

You can't in simple words.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you misunderstand the meaning of `where T : struct` and `where T : class`.

A generic [type constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx) like this means that `T` must be a **value type** or a **reference type** respectively.

However, the purpose of an interface is to define a ***contract***, which is a totally different concept as compared to value type vs. reference type semantics.

Therefore a restriction like `where T : interface` would make no sense.

If you want to know more, I would suggest you to read the C# Programming Guide on type constraints:

> **[Constraints on Type Parameters (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx)**

Comment: A constraint as interface type would make sense if there were language features which would be usable on such types and only such types.  For example, it would be very helpful if one could define a `Wrapper<T>:T where T:interface(Foo)`, with the semantics that the class would define a field `Foo` of type `T`, and explicitly implement each member `m` of the interface `T` by having it invoke `Foo.m`.  Such a general facility would not be workable with classes, even with CLR support, but could be quite useful with interfaces if the CLR provided the necessary features.

Answer (score 0):

> This fails because C# will only allow types after the base class to be interfaces

This constraint is due to the lack of multiple inheritance in C#. Multiple inheritance can be approximated by the use of interfaces because the overriding methods are explicit. The same way a class can only extend one other class, but can implement multiple interfaces. The trick here is that the implementing class MUST define the body for a method, so that the implementation is specific on which method is called.

Using a where to limit T can be applied to one class, or several interfaces. You can not limit the range to several classes.